# overriding UserClaimsPrincipalFactory generateclaimsasync method doesn't make claims stick

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core-identity

I have overridden the userclaimsprincipalfactory like this:

```
 public class CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User, Role>
{
    public CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<User> userManager, RoleManager<Role> roleManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(User user)
    {
        var id = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email));

        return id;
    }
}
```

And also added the factory to my identity configuration like this:

```
 services.AddIdentityMongoDbProvider<User, Role>(identityOptions =>
        {
            identityOptions.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            identityOptions.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            identityOptions.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            identityOptions.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            identityOptions.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        }, mongoIdentityOptions => {
            mongoIdentityOptions.ConnectionString = configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"];
        }).AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

If i add a breakpoint to my GenerateClaimsAsync method i can see that it adds the claims as it should (somehow it adds the claim like 10 times, even tho it only hits the method once).

Later on when i want to get one of the claims out i do this:

```
   protected string GetUsername()
    {
        if (User != null && User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type.Equals(UserClaims.UserName)))
        {
            var claimValue = User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(w => w.Type == UserClaims.UserName);
            return claimValue?.Value;
        }

        throw new HttpException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
```

Here User is of type ClaimsPrincipal and the object looks like the one i added the claims to but there are no claims anywhere in that object.

this is the code i use to signin:

```
 public async Task<UserDto> Login(LoginDataContract dataContract)
    {
        var appUser = userManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Email == dataContract.Email);

        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(dataContract.Email, dataContract.Password, false, false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var jwtObject = AuthenticationHelper.GenerateJwtToken(dataContract.Email, appUser, appSettings);

            var userDto = mapper.Map<User, UserDto>(appUser);

            userDto.Token = jwtObject.token;
            userDto.TokenExpiresIn = jwtObject.expiresIn;
            return userDto;
        }

        throw new Exception("Failed to login!");
    }
```

How come the claims doesn't stay?

Comment: yeah sorry that was another try to use custom claims. i removed that from the question